# Adjusting rectangle vertices in igraph python

Tags: python, igraph

I need to adjust my rectangle vertices width and height but don't know how to. Is there a "vertex.size2" equivalent of R in python?

I tried "vertex_size_2" and "vertex_size2" but none of them did anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no equivalent of `vertex.size2` in Python yet.